# Making sure that /usr/local/bin is in my $PATH

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been running into various issues with Node/NPM after upgrading to Catalina OS. Anyway, to make a long story short, I just went ahead and used the Node installer. Now at the end of the successful installation it adds this note:

> Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

I think this is my issue. Currently this is not the case on my machine. My simple question is: how do I do this? How do I make sure that /usr/local/bin is in my $PATH?

FYI, when I run `echo $PATH` I get this:

```
/Users/muirik/.npm-global/bin:/Users/muirik/.npm-global/bin:/Users/muirik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/Users/muirik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/Users/muirik/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/muirik/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
muirik@Mac-mini ~ %
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add it there, e.g., in your `.bash_profile`, or `.zshrc`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: Question, right now that works for me. But when I close and reopen a terminal, I have to add that every time to get it to work. Is there something I can do to make this permanent?

Comment: @Muirik add it to some file that's loaded when you open a terminal, such as `.bash_profile`, assuming you're using bash

Comment: Catalina uses zsh so I added it to my .zshrc file and that worked. Many thanks!